# "SVN": Is it possible to break a big patch into several successive ones before any check-in?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have to break a big patch into several small ones. Say p1, p2, p3. Before they are all reviewed, none of them can be checked in.

But these patches have dependencies like p3 -> p2 -> p1.

SVN seems always generate patch based on the version in repo. So how can we create such successive patches without check in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unless you made changes to multiple files and you you can logically and atomically divide them into multiple commits / patches. Use branches and don't forget to make atomic commits in *commit early, commit often* mode.

Note that TortoiseSVN provides **Restore after commit** command that maybe will help you. Read [TortoiseSVN | Committing only parts of files](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-commit.html#tsvn-dug-commit-restore).

BTW, checkpoining feature is on the [roadmap of Apache Subversion project](http://subversion.apache.org/roadmap.html#next-release-status) and recently there was some progress. Maybe the feature will be released with one of the next major updates -- not in the upcoming SVN 1.10, but probably in SVN 1.11.

Comment: With git, I can do these all locally before push to remote and then abandon the experimental branch if necessary. Maybe this is one more reason I should get along with git.

Comment: @smwikipedia you are right that it's possible with git. However, both SVN and git have their downsides. If checkpointing is important for you, use git. :)